# Visual Studio Cordova and Kendo UI always fails at scrollElement

Tags: kendo-ui, visual-studio-cordova

I was trying out Visual Studio Cordova and Kendo UI.
I pasted a simple code from the Kendo UI examples then I initialized kendo in deviceready.
No matter what example I'm using the compiler always fails with the following error:
**JavaScript runtime error: Unable to get property 'scrollElement' of undefined or null reference**
Which point me on kendo.all.min.js to:
`t.scroller=t.content.data("kendoMobileScroller"),t.scrollerContent=t.scroller.scrollElement`

By running the index.html file (initializing kendo inside it) all works fine.

Does anybody has an idea about this?

Comment: I'm having the same issue here. I think it has to do with the newest version of Cordova in the CTP3 release of the tools for Visual Studio. One project of mine is using CTP2 and that one seems to work correctly.

Comment: Question: If you have a modal popup in the index.html, can you try to remove it?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problem until I enabled native scrolling support:

```
new kendo.mobile.Application(document.body, { useNativeScrolling: true });
```